# How to convert a file to binary stream in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a website by using Next.js and trying to upload a file to OneDrive by using [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The document says the request body should be the binary stream of the file to be uploaded, but I don't know how to convert it to binary stream.

I am using HTML input element to save file data to `file`:

`{name: '200311 Weekly Safety Meeting - Coronavirus (2019-nCoV).pdf', lastModified: 1644421523745, lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 09 2022 07:45:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 700913, …}`

My code on the client side,

```
const uploadFile = async () => {
    const res = await axios.put('/api/onedrive/file', {
        accessToken: token,
        filename: file.name,
        content: file,
        parentId: '01XA3PFKG7YWH2K7QVIZCYRP33XLQEHLZG',
    });
    console.log(res.data);
};
```

On the server side,

```
const upload = async (req, res) => {
const { filename, accessToken, content, parentId } = req.body;
const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/69e5bc0d-ef63-4040-88cf-0ada867b7afa/drive/items/${parentId}:/${filename}:/content`;

try {
    const result = await axios({
        method: 'put',
        url: url,
        body: content,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
    });
    res.status(200).send(result.data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out

Please try the below code for converting file into binary format, see if it works

Code:

```
function GetBinaryDataFromFile(strFileName)
{
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fso.Type = 1
    fso.Open
    fso.LoadFromFile strFileName
}
```

Comment: I got `ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined`. I think `ActiveXObject` is available only on IE browser.

Comment: Yes I think ActiveXObject is part of IE only and will work only with it. It will not work with other browsers as it is not supported for security reasons.